# How to connect to repository using TortoiseHg workbench?

Tags: mercurial, repository, tortoisehg

I am noob at things like these. At work team leader installed Mercurial in my PC. And created folder. After doing several things he connected my folder with folder in his PC. I forgot what he did. Now I need to connect my home PC to that folder. If there is a tutorial for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I need to connect my home PC to that folder.

You **really need** to learn Mercurial **terminology** and Mercurial **basics** - before all

You must (in Mercurial Terms)
- clone TeamLeader repo
- add this clone (you local repo, linked to leader's) to your WorkBench

Before cloning I'll suggest checking the docs (link from Martin above) **as a must** and read [TortoiseHG QuickStart Guide](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.2/quick.html), grok it and adapt to your project's needs (URL of repo to clone)

Comment: i can work with repo.But only dont know how to connect it to folder

Comment: You **don't** "connect to folder". You have some **related repositories**, which can be used as pull-push targets. And on cloning cloned repo *automagically* remember parent repo as default

Answer (score 12):

There is the [TortoiseHg documentation](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.1/). It's quite good and has a description of the common tasks. What I think you're looking for is the *Open Repository* menu item in the [*File* menu](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.1/workbench.html#workbench-menus):

[image: TortoiseHg File menu]

As the menu says, you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> as a keyboard shortcut. That will add it to the Repository Registry in the left side of the workbench.

---

Turns out it wasn't the *Open Repository* item after all. My next guess is that clicking two arrows in the [Task Toolbar](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.1/workbench.html#task-toolbar) will help. That brings up the Synchronize Window where you can add a new *path* to repository settings. That's the bottom left side here:

[image: Synchronize Window]

Pick the type in the first drop-down (pick "local" if you can browse to the repository on your file system) and then enter the path to the repository. Click the little floppy disk icon to the right to save the path. Use the name `default` to make it the default push and pull path.

If the team leader's repository is accessed over HTTP, then you need the right host name or IP address to be able to connect. You should have gotten this information from the team leader.

If you start by opening the team leader's repository, then you'll find it listed in the bottom right side. You can then click on the repository and save the path.

Comment: i already done this.But how to connect to other folder in other computer ? now i search in documentation for it.thx for link :)

Comment: I've added some more, maybe this is the dialog you're searching for?

Comment: he used his ip adress to connect.where to put it ?

Comment: i really confused.what to do know ?maybe i need take my notebook to work and copy paste settings

Comment: I think you need to talk with the team leader.

Comment: i am also.but he said do yourself it is so easy

Comment: I also suggest reading up on basic Mercurial concepts such as push and pull paths. See `hg help paths` on a command line.

Comment: Also, make sure to name your repository-alias default.. since it is the default and if you don't name it default, you have to select it every single time manually!!! see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321065/how-do-i-make-tortoise-hg-remember-a-repository .